# What is the set of all joint distributions from two given marginal distributions?

Tags: self-study, distributions

I'm trying to make sense of the [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric), it says in wikipedia

[image]

Say the marginal distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$ are given, what properties does a joint distribution from the two need to satisfy? For example like $\mu(x)=\int p(x,y)dx$ and $\nu(y)=\int p(x,y)dy$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint distribution just needs to be a valid probability distribution, with matching marginals. That's it.

It turns out that you can characterize the set of such distributions via [copulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)). That is, if we assume for now that $X$ and $Y$ are each real-valued, every such distribution has cdf of the form
$$
\Pr(X \le x, Y \le y) = C(\Pr(X \le x), \Pr(Y \le y))
$$
where $C$ is the joint cdf of a distribution that has uniform margins on the unit square. The converse also holds: any such $C$ gives you a valid joint distribution. I'm pretty sure something analogous holds for $X$ and $Y$ taking values in $\mathbb R^n$, but apparently it only holds in one direction [for infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06941).

That doesn't necessarily help you in computing the Wasserstein distance, but it might help in thinking about what it means.

Comment: Ohhh, cool paper!